# Jenkins plugin shows on Plugin page but does not show on configuration page

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating a hello world plugin for Jenkins by following [Tutorial: Create a Jenkins Plugin to integrate Jenkins and Nexus Repository](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/tutorial-create-a-jenkins-plugin-to-integrate-jenkins-and-nexus-repository/#part1). After I followed the steps, I can run Jenkins and test the plugin.

It shows on Installed Plugin Page.

[image]

Then I go to Configuration page and expect to see `Hello World Builder` section like the below image, but there is not.
[image]

What steps did I miss? Is there anything I have to do before having that plugin show up on the configuration page?

**Update**
This is the project layout, I haven't modified anything on it yet.
[image]

Comment: Did you rename the plugin from HelloWorldBuilder? if so you need to rename the resources (jelly scripts) to match https://github.com/jenkinsci/hello-world-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/hello_world/HelloWorldBuilder

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn No, I didn't. I also uploaded project's layout on the question.

Comment: Do the package names between resources and code match? since you did show the package names, we cannot be sure. This is one of the major reason for not showing anything.

Comment: @blackbuild Yes, their name match. The packagename is xxx.cd.infologgerplugin and the root directory under src/main/resources is xxx. The reason I censored package's name is part of my company's policy. :)

Comment: My problem was that the folder under the resources was not created as com -> plugin -> MyClass but as com.plugin.MyClass, this causes the jar to not be packaged correctly. Check if you jar is packaged ok

Answer (score 1):

What command did you use to generate the plugin skeleton?

FYI, from the tutorial above, `mvn -cpu` is deprecated.

To generate the plugin skeleton, use:

`mvn hpi:create`

or

`mvn -U org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:create` from the Jenkins [Plugin tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial)

I'm going to include each step for what worked for me:

1. `mvn hpi:create`, then enter groupId (press enter to use default: *org.jenkins-ci.plugins*) and artifactId (name of the plugin)
2. `cd new-plugin-name`
3. `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
4. `mvn package`
5. `mvn hpi:run`
   (default port is 8080, but you can set your own with `Dport` option (i.e. `mvn hpi:run -Dport=9999`, use this if port 8080 is in use - otherwise `mvn hpi:run` will fail)
6. Open browser and enter URL "localhost:8080" (or 9999)
7. You should the page below.  Click the link and that'll take you to Jenkins home page [image]
8. Click 'Manage Jenkins' > Configure System.  Scroll down near the bottom of the page and you should see the Hello World Builder section [image]
9. Go back to Jenkins home page and click New Item
10. Give the project any name, select Freestyle Project, click OK.
11. Scroll down to the Build section and click 'Add build step' > Say hello world
12. Enter a name (i.e. TestName), save the project, then run a build ('Build Now')
13. Click on the latest build under 'Build History' > Console Output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and solved it.
I am sure you are using eclipse as IDE and imported HelloWorldBuilder as a maven project.

In my case, I converted it to eclipse project after deleted and regenerated again.
Please refer "Setting up a productive environment with you IDE" section of the following url and use this command.

`mvn -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true -DoutputDirectory=target/eclipse-classes -Declipse.workspace=/path/to/workspace eclipse:eclipse eclipse:add-maven-repo`

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial

If you launch the project after convert and rebuild it, the hello world builder section will be shown in your jenkins configuration menu.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. Apparently currently (see date of this message) master of the hello world example is wrong. I needed to change

`<artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>`

to

`<artifactId>hello_world</artifactId>`

because some component in the middle doesn't accept "-". I think hpi:create will tell you that, unfortunately the debug log files don't. But the existing hello-world should already have those things correct.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced same problem, I think reason is because I imported to eclipse as a maven project. I deleted folder and ran command

```
mvn -U org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:create
```

to create new project. Then ran `mvn hpi:run` and it showed up well.